# background-image wont show in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, css, background-image

Im trying to put an link to a page and put an image as background (which would change when you hover on it). Im using the following code :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <div>
        <a href="WebForm.aspx" style="width:250px; height: 250px; background-image:url(Ressources/catalogueGC.jpg);" ></a>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

No matter what I've tried the image wont show in the div. If I put some text between the `<a>` and the `</a>`, the text shows correctly, however no trace of the image. I'm 100% sure the image does not 404 and its url is correct.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: You sure that image path is correct relative to the page?

Comment: @3rror404 Yes, i've verified

Comment: Your width and height will have no effect unless you use `display:block` on the `<a>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchors are inline elements.

You need to add this to your css:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Now, it will take up the width and height, and will be able to show the background. `inline-block` will cause it to behave like a block element, but still remain inline.

Answer (score 2):

By default anchor elements are displayed inline.

Assign `display:block` CSS property to the anchor.

```
<a href="WebForm.aspx" style="display:block; width:250px; height: 250px; background-image:url(Ressources/catalogueGC.jpg);" ></a>
```